# Getting Multiple messages on spark-submit "seeking to EARLIEST and Resetting offset for partition topic-partition"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am running **spark 2.4.4** on a virtual machine and reading kafka topic in batch mode. What kafka consumer configuration can cause this ?

Getting numerous messages like below and spark job is running forever.

```
    20/06/14 09:00:43 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor-2, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor] 
Seeking to EARLIEST offset of partition topic-12
    20/06/14 09:00:44 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor-3, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor] 
Resetting offset for partition topic-38 to offset 0.
    20/06/14 09:00:44 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor-3, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor] 
Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic-38
    20/06/14 09:00:44 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor-2, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor] 
Resetting offset for partition topic-12 to offset 0.
    20/06/14 09:00:44 INFO SubscriptionState: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor-2, groupId=spark-kafka-relation-de56e437-85a0-4431-bb02-faca7b3487ab-executor] 
Seeking to LATEST offset of partition topic-12
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Flink. Did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66228274/how-to-avoid-continuous-resetting-offset-and-seeking-to-latest-offset